# Send image by AJAX on server (Django) from canvas (fabric.js)

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, coffeescript, fabricjs

Can I send image on my server from canvas? I tried this code. But it isn't working:

[image]

Coffeescript:

```
getElement = (id) ->
  document.getElementById(id)

titleInput = getElement 'id_title'
subscriptionInput = getElement 'id_subscription'
submitButton = getElement 'submit'

canvas = new fabric.Canvas 'canvas', {backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)'}

saveImage = (e) ->
  subscription = subscriptionInput.value
  title = titleInput.value
  image = canvas.toDataURL {format: 'jpeg',quality: 0.8}
  data = {title: title, subscription: subscription, image: image}
  $.ajax {type: 'POST', url: '', data: data}

submitButton.addEventListener 'click', saveImage, false
```

What can I do?

Comment: You should explain what you mean by `it isn't working`, perhaps detailing what you'd expect and what is actually happening.

Comment: url: ''? i'm not a cofeescript expert but looks like the url is missing.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi it's correct. When url is empty, request will be sent on current url

Comment: @DanCornilescu I think screenshot which I added to question will help you to understand :)